# Will daily push-ups help to get rid of my belly fat?

Tags: weight-loss, push-ups, fat, bellyfat

I've never made real exercise. Recently i began doing push-ups starting with
1 a day and finally increasing it to 15 day. Sometimes doing it 3-4 times (45-60).

If i continue this routine, will it help to reduce my belly fat?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not do sit ups and use those abs?

Comment: Why not do pushups, situps and pullups and work out your entire upper body?

Comment: actually it has been proven that push ups are better for the abs than sit ups, In a sit up  most of the work is being done by the deep hip flexors

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply put; no.

Diet is 80% of the battle when it comes to weight loss. Focus on this before any other area.

Also, you cannot 'spot-reduce' fat.

Push-ups are a useful exercise but they should not be your only exercise. Too many push-ups (and little else) will lead to posture issues.

Consider adding squats, pull-ups, planks etc - these are compound exercises that'll hit more than one area.

Comment: Could you narrow those "posture issues" a little bit? What can happen to be exact. Thank you

Comment: If you only strengthen the muscles used in the push-up, you're upper body will be unbalanced. You need to work on the muscles in your back equally (generally done through pull ups etc).

Comment: @adamnuttall Could you provide a source for your posture comment?

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwibia_y2cfKAhUCJQ8KHda2Bg0QFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.builtlean.com%2F2011%2F11%2F28%2Fposture-problems%2F&usg=AFQjCNFBNhiCAsEgluVsqw84jTVw8ogoZA&sig2=joGuxv1g117422X0sMEWFw

Answer (score 12):

Any time you exercise to the point of increasing your daily caloric burn higher than your caloric intake, you will burn fat. The body alone will decide where to take that fat from. Adding to or toning muscle in an area is not equivalent to losing fat in that same area.

Comment: ..and remmeber that it's also possible and likely to burn muscle.  The amount which will depend on the intesity and type of exercise performed. Hence the general recommendation to excercise in the ~65% of max HR to maximise fat loss.  Different levels of exercise will hit different energy sources first.

Answer (score -4):

Yes,you will lose weight if you do push-ups everyday.But it depends on how many you do. Doing just 50-100 push-ups isn't going to make a huge difference.You have to go for 200 to 300 push-ups everyday to see any decent changes. And a another point is that you also have to have a good diet.Stop eating junk food and eat more protein.