# Upper body toning

Tags: upper-body-workout

Whats the best exercise moves to target toning of the area (flab) that sticks out between your chest, arm and shoulder when wearing sleeveless tops?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot target any particular area of the body for fat loss. The body will remove fat from the areas that it feels like need to be reduced first. Proper diet and exercise will decrease your body fat overall, and eventually your body will get to that.

See also:

- [How can I get a flat stomach?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-can-i-get-a-flat-stomach)
- [Will daily push-ups help to get rid of my belly fat?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/118/will-daily-push-ups-help-to-get-rid-of-my-belly-fat)
- [How to lose manboobs?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/718/how-to-lose-manboobs)

All of these have also the same response. Just keep working at fat loss in general and eventually you'll see the results you're looking for.